# Rails/Bundler precompile vs lazy compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

In the `config/application.rb` file in a Rails app, there's the following section of code:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
    # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
    Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
    # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
    # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

I'm perhaps not clear what `Bundler.require` is doing. I was under the impression that it required the specified sections in the Gemfile, but I'm not clear as to why `Bundler.require *Rails.groups(...)` causes it to precompile and `Bundler.require(...)` causes assets to be lazily loaded.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

These lines don't actually change how your assets are used.

The first line,

```
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
```

only loads gems from the `assets` group in your development and test environment.  This means that things like `sass-rails` and `uglifier` won't be available in production, which then means that you won't be able to properly compile/minify/whatever your assets on the fly in production if you're making use of those gems.

On the other hand,

```
Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
```

will load the `assets` group in any environment, making those gems available in production to do asset compilation/minification/whatever on the fly.

So, as stated above, these lines don't actually change the behaviour of your asset pipeline - it simply means that you should use the first if you're going to precompile your assets for production, or use the second if you're going to lazily compile in production.

Comment: If your pre-compiling assets is there any reason not to just put the asset gems directly in Gemfile without a group if they are being included in every environment anyway?

Comment: @Kris basically it allows you to switch between the two strategies easily. If you want to switch, you won't need to move `gem ...` lines around