# Rails 3.2.6 routing error for fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, fonts, routes, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.2.6 based application using web-app-theme gem. After deploying in production I seeing following errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

```
[Wed Jul 18 23:00:14 2012] [error] [client 50.53.58.188] Premature end of script headers: fonts, referer: https://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
[ pid=8920 thr=139857209571072 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:819 time=2012-07-18 23:00:14.743 ]: The backend application (process 9474) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.
[ pid=9474 thr=9488700 file=utils.rb:176 time=2012-07-18 23:00:14.744 ]: *** Exception ActionController::RoutingError in application (No route matches [GET] "/assets/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.svg") (process 9474, thread #<Thread:0x00000001219278>):
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
.....
```

I have placed the mentioned file `museosans_500-webfont.svg` in `app/assets/fonts/` directory.  But why I am still this error. I also see similar error for other assets like `/assets/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.ttf`, etc.

Any feedback is much appreciated. Thanks.
-- Atarangp

Answer (score 0):

Try add fonts dir to assets path in environment.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

Comment: Meduza Thanks, but after adding these entries to the environment.rb I got phusion exceptions for line containing "config". My application.rb file  already has "config.assets.enabled = true" entry. So I added your second entry to the application.rb but got the same (orginal) error. Should I add these entries to the production.rb or test.rb file?

Comment: Sorry, I have this line in application.rb!

Comment: Look at this, maybe it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673988/rails-bundler-precompile-vs-lazy-compile

Comment: Meduza, thanks again but it didn't fix the issue. I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

The url in your CSS / HTML seems to be wrong:

`/assets/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.svg`

You should change that to:

`/assets/museosans_500-webfont.svg`

But **keep** the file on the `app/assets/fonts` directory.

Comment: You might want to also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329137/how-to-add-a-custom-font-to-rails-app) related answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when integrating the Katex library.

The issue is that Rails' Asset Pipeline compiles the assets into the `public/assets` directory without keeping the `fonts` or `images` or `javascript` directories.

So when you're looking for `/assets/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.svg`, it doesn't exist, that font has been compiled to `/assets/museosans_500-webfont.svg`.

To solve this you have two options:

1. **Update the path in the CSS or JS:**

   `/assets/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.svg`

   becomes

   `/assets/museosans_500-webfont.svg`
2. **Put the fonts in a `fonts` subdirectory:**

   *If you don't want to (or can't) update the CSS or JS (e.g. it's a minified third party library), then you can use the following method to ensure that there is a `public/assets/fonts` directory that contains all your fonts.*

   Simply put your font(s) in the following path:

   `/assets/fonts/fonts/museosans_500-webfont.svg`

   Now your `public/assets` directory will contain a `fonts` directory and your GET request will be happy.

*For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29475775/293280).*