# font glyphicons not working with bootstrap 3 and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I cannot get glyphicons to work with bootstrap 3 and rails.  I've scowered the internet and nothing i find helps.  In my bootstrap.css file i have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

In application.rb, I have:

```
config.assets.enabled = true  
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts" 
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

I have already tried running:

rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development

In application.js I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

In application.css I have:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require bootstrap
 */
```

All my fonts are stored in assets/fonts

I've already looked at the following and none of them have worked:

[Bootstrap 3+Rails 4 - Certain Glyphicons not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962775/bootstrap-3rails-4-certain-glyphicons-not-working)

[How to add a custom font to Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329137/how-to-add-a-custom-font-to-rails-app)

How can I fix this?

Comment: The first thing I would try after looking briefly is to place "require tree ." after "require bootstrap" in app.js and app.css.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but its not working.  I don't think that's the issue because the page is including all of the files and they seem to be in the right order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap-sass gem, follow my setup below. If not give it a try, it's the easiest bootstrap setup that I've used.

By the way I'm currently using rails Versions 4.1.6 and 4.1.8

Two gems

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

Your Application.js should look like this below (turbolinks optional)

```
  /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Style sheet should have these two imports

```
/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

if this setup doesn't work for you try 
font-path
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

**section 2.3.2 css and sass**

so your code would go from:

```
url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

to 
font-path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading bootstrap gems, if you use them, fixed it for me:

`gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'`

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my fix.

Because I previously precompiled my assets locally, then added glyphicons after, heroku was not picking up those assets. So I had to re-compile them locally again by doing:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

git add public/assets

git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

And pushing to heroku

```
git push heroku master
```

from heroku: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction