# How do I use a custom font in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass, webfonts

I have

`users.scss`

```
@font-face {
  font-family: scriptina;
  src: asset-url('scriptina.ttf')
}

.script {
  font: scriptina, cursive; 
}
```

Which generates

```
@font-face {
  font-family: scriptina;
  src: url(/scriptina.ttf);
}
/* line 18, C:/Users/Chloe/workspace//app/assets/stylesheets/users.scss */
.script {
  font: scriptina, cursive;
}
```

But `http://localhost:3000/scriptina.ttf` generates

> Routing Error 
> No route matches [GET] "/scriptina.ttf"

```
$ ls app/assets
config  images  javascripts  scriptina.ttf  stylesheets
```

Rails 5

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329137/how-to-add-a-custom-font-to-rails-app/21427234#21427234) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329137/how-to-add-a-custom-font-to-rails-app/21427138#21427138)This will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method (outlined [here](https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570)) would be to add a `fonts` folder to `app/assets`, and then add it to the folders that your app will look for assets in by editing `config/application.rb`:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Then move `scriptina.ttf` into `app/assets/fonts` and your `asset-url` helper will then be referencing a valid path to your font.

Comment: Hmm, I always thought it searched all of `assets/` to find things. I modified `config/initializers/assets.rb` instead due to this comment: `# Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers`. I added `Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")`. Also had to change `font:` to `font-family: scriptina, cursive;`.