# Rails 3.2 coffeescript works fine in development but won't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have an event handler on keyup defined in coffeescript:

```
$('#query_raw_query').keyup ->
    clearsearch()
```

This works fine in development (clearsearch is defined earlier in the coffee file).  However when I deploy, it doesn't work and I don't see any errors anywhere.  I've tried manually compiling assets, I've tried setting

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in production.rb, I've tried moving coffee-rails out of the :assets scope in my Gemfile.

```
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
```

I'm out of ideas, anyone have any idea why this wouldn't work, or at least where I could look for errors?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be similar to this one:

[Coffeescript/Javascript Is Not Working on Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832470/coffeescript-javascript-is-not-working-on-server)

Have a try there and see if it works for you.